# MongoDB PHP Driver "No suitable servers found"

Tags: php, mongodb, backend

I'm installing a MongoDB on Debian 9 but when I try to connect 
"No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection refused calling ismaster on '127.0.0.1:27017']" is raised.

The machine runs
**Debian 9** 
**PHP PHP 7.0.27-0+deb9u1**
**MongoDB Version 3.6.5**
**MongoDB database driver   1.6.16 (stable)**
    **MongoDB driver for PHP   1.4.3 (stable)**

I googled all the pages that talked about this thread but nothing.
I also changed the mongod.conf, deleted the ipv6 lookback, but nothing.

The script that I launch in PHP is

```
use MongoDB\Client;

$user = 'xxxx';
$pwd = 'yyyy';
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$port = '27017';
$db_name = 'my_db';

$mongo = new Client("mongodb://".$user.":".$pwd."@".$host.":".$port);
return $mongo->selectDatabase($db_name);
```

When I try to

```
selectDatabase()
```

the exception was raised

PS: Of course, $user and $pwd are credentials of a user that I correctly create in "admin" Mongo's table

```
{
"_id" : "admin.root",
"user" : "root",
"db" : "admin",
"credentials" : {
    "SCRAM-SHA-1" : {
        "iterationCount" : 10000,
        "salt" : "<hidden>",
        "storedKey" : "<hidden>",
        "serverKey" : "<hidden>"
    }
},
"roles" : [
    {
        "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
        "db" : "admin"
    }
]
```

}

Help please o_O

**EDIT**: Before deploying the project on live server I tested it on MAMP and everything work properly (in particular the connection with Mongo DB)

Comment: are you sure the mongo server is running and are you able to connect to the mongo server from the command line ?

Comment: @ᴄʀᴏᴢᴇᴛ of course.
 `● mongod.service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-05-29 17:24:11 CEST; 14h ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
 Main PID: 1961 (mongod)
    Tasks: 23
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
           └─1961 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`

And also I'm able to access Mongo SHELL with and without authorization with this command

`mongo --port 27017 -u "xxxx" -p "yyyy" --authenticationDatabase "admin"`